# How can I make findViewById get the id attibute on the XML dynamically (Android)?

Tags: android, xml, view, itemizedoverlay

Tipically you would have this:

```
        Activity parent = (Activity) context;
                dragImage = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.what_ever_you_defined_on_xml);
```

However, in my case I want "findViewById" to get the id attribute dinamically because I have more than one attribute depending on what kind of OverlayItem the user want on the Map (Open Street Map).  I have tried this but my application crash:

```
        Activity parent = (Activity) context;
                View v = parent.getCurrentFocus();  
    dragImage = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(v.getId());
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

---

More details to add context:

```
public Itemizedoverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context, MapView map) {

super(defaultMarker, new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(context));
this.defaultMarker = defaultMarker;

this.map = map;

// Setup for dragging:
// Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle):

Activity parent = (Activity) context;
View v = parent.getCurrentFocus();  
dragImage = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(v.getId());

xDragImageOffset = dragImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;
yDragImageOffset = dragImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
}
```

In the XML:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/drag1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/symbol1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    /> 

    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/drag2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/symbol2"
    android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/drag3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/symbol3"
    android:visibility="gone"
    /> 

    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/drag4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/symbol4"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't your end result simply yield the same thing as:

```
dragImage = (ImageView)v;
```

Comment: Steve,

Thanks for your suggestion.  I had tried what you suggest (downcasting) but still the application is crashing.

Comment: Is the item that's focused NOT an ImageView

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? I am still not clear.  By the way, I was running the debugger and its say that v is null so dragImage is getting nothing.

Comment: OK, can you post more code then to give more context?  Perhaps just a null check before doing anything to dragImage will fix the issue.  What I was saying in my last comment was that perhaps you were getting a type cast exception when trying to cast your view (v) to ImageView...

Comment: I understand what you said.  However, dragImage cannot be null.  I had added more code to give more context.